# Doctrine Query Builder, how to escape single quote?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to run a replace query, like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('q');

$qb->where("REPLACE(q.name,'-','') = :q")->setParameter('q', $q);

return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
```

This will work fine.

The problem is I try to replace a single quote `"REPLACE(q.name,'\'','') = :q"`

It will complain it cannot escape it.

same with `"REPLACE(q.name,'\\'','') = :q"` or `"REPLACE(q.name,\"'\",'') = :q"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a second parameter? Since `REPLACE` not exists in Doctrine by default, i think you have add the `beberlei/DoctrineExtensions` package. With this package the following will work.

```php
$qb->where("REPLACE(q.name,:s,'') = :q")
    ->setParameter('q', $q)
    ->setParameter('s', "'");
```